# convert query result to parquet

Tags: go, grpc

I have a grpc server and a gRPC client in golang, I want to execute a query in the server and send back the result to the client, the query may differ time to time (number of columns and their types are not specified) , my goal is converting that query result to parquet and send it to the client , how could I do that?